# How can I do this port-forward?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

Hello I try to do a port forward in this network

[image]

As you can see I have the localhost when I want to execute a curl to localhost:9203, in order to get access to 10.0.0.1:9200.

10.0.0.1:9200 is a server that only is accessible by ssh server, 10.0.0.0.

Currently, I connect by ssh to ssh server and then I execute the curl, but I want to do this from localhost because I cannot install dependencies in ssh server.

How can I do this port-for

I need access to ssh server with a user and password.

how can I do a port forward or ssh server needs a firewall rule to redirect?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your question, I assume you are wanting to use an SSH tunnel.

ssh -L 9203:10.0.0.1:9200 user@10.0.0.0
(replace user with an actual user on 10.0.0.0)

That will open up 9203 on your local machine, and redirect traffic to 10.0.0.1 on 9200.

Comment: this `ssh -L 9203:elastic_ip.3:9200 user@sshserver` doesn't redirect trafic only get a access to the ssh server.

Comment: bind [elastic_ip]:9200: Cannot assign requested address
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 9200

Comment: Is the port in use? netstat -ltmp

Comment: no, elasticsearch is a server that is only accesible by ssh server